# Woocommerce guest checkout not redirecting to order-received page

Tags: wordpress, function, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

I have created a flow using a function that when someone try to make an order without login he/she is redirected to a custom login-register pages where they choose to either login/register or continue as a guest - see function code below, now when someone makes an order he/she gets redirected to custom login-register page instead of order-received page. What's wrong here?

```
function ace_redirect_pre_checkout() {
if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' )) 
    $redirect_page_id = 104549;
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_page(17)) {
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($redirect_page_id));
   
    } elseif (is_user_logged_in() && is_page($redirect_page_id)) {
      wp_redirect(get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('checkout')));
    
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'ace_redirect_pre_checkout');
```

Comment: 104549 is custom login/register page id and 17 is default checkout page id

Comment: What is `is_page( 17 )` ?

Comment: Page 17 is Checkout page